# Best approach for rails app/api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I'm developing a rails app, it's a regular site, but I need to develop an API, so I was reading and trying some stuff, the options that I've thought are (others are welcome):

- Versioning the API and separate the API from the controller.
  Pro: Clean and separate stuff. Cons: the need to handle 2 controllers for the same task.
- Not versioning and keep everything in the same controllers, views can be done with jbuilder. Pro: not really easy way to version it. Cons: harder to expose only parts of the app. harder to route stuff like in an versioned way.

I really want to avoid duplication, but I need some way to avoid that, and make some nice routes like in a versioned way, I don't want to have more than 1 controller for some type of object, in a versioned way if you have 3 versions you'll end up with 4 controllers, that is a lot to maintain.

Please correct me if I'm wrong, and hope to get some good answers :)

Thanks.

Comment: thanks to both of you, I knew that it was the best path to follow, but I wasn't sure enough, I'm using devise and a lot of stuff so seems the right choice to version it, and keep a good api for the public...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Versioning your API is the best route to take.

If you have 4 versions, 1 controller, you still only need to maintain 2 controller (the one in the web facing application, and the most recent version of the API.)

If you have write access in your API, you would be able to take advantage of your own API in your application and not need to create a `new` method in both the API and in the main application (AJAX).

It is possible that your filters are different. You may need different types of authentication for the API and the main application.

The biggest argument for versioning would probably be that if you have anyone other than yourself consuming the API, their application would not break the day you deploy your changes.

Besides, you should keep to the 'thin controllers, fat models' mentality. That would prevent a lot of duplication with that alone.

Answer (score 0):

I always code api within their own namespace because these points could be very different from the main app:

- format rules
- auth
- rescue
- versioning
- before / after filters

Even if you have duplication in controllers, there should not be much code, and I cant see why it would be a big deal. Actually it could even force you to abstract your code and have thin controllers.